# Sound starts working after first sleep

Tags: sound

I was on 16.04, but now I have upgraded to 18.04 but still one issue has not gone. On turning on the PC, sound doesn't work until I make the PC sleep and wake it up again. What may be the issue, and how to fix it?

Comment: The time consuming solution would be running `journalctl -b` and comparing messages between boot and resume.

Comment: I too am having this problem (but with 22.04) did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @JamesHardy No, I don't remember fixing this. I think I just switched to a different OS then.